# get kivy widget to format and update at the same time

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy

I'm having a hard time understanding how the layouts and the apps work together in kivy. I'm trying to build a simple ui for a basic stock ticker. My data module will hand back a dictionary of current price: xxx, last price: xxx, change: xxx

I simple want to display this information in kivy, letting it auto-update via the Clock schedule. I played around with a bunch of labels and getting them to poll. That worked, but I couldn't figure out a clean way to format them. I could not get GridLayout to work.

I'm now trying to get a ListView, but it doesn't display anything on the screen. this is driving me nutz. Does someone have a good walkthrough that shows the relationship of the front end and the back end on kivy? The docs don't really go into this and I can't find any code samples.

Here's what I have (note: the ListWidget's update DOES run, I see its output in the console, but there's nothing in the ui window).

```
class ListWidget(ListView):
    def update(self, dt):
        day = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%d %S')
        hour = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%H %S')
        print hour

        self.data = [day, hour]


class MainView(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['cols'] = 2
        kwargs['size_hint'] = (1.0, 1.0)
        super(MainView, self).__init__(**kwargs)


class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        main = MainView()
        list_widget = ListWidget()
        list_widget.data = ['date', 'time']
        main.add_widget(list_widget)
        Clock.schedule_interval(main.children[0].update, 1)

        return main

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main = MainApp()
    main.run()
```

Comment: Does re-sizing the window update the view?

Comment: it doesn't seem to, but i'll revisit the code when I have a chance.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old but here is the modificated code, that is adding a label with the current value onto the Widget maybe it helps someone.

```py
class ListWidget(ListView):

    def update(self, dt):
        day = datetime.now().strftime('%d %S')
        hour = datetime.now().strftime('%H %S')
        print hour

        self.clear_widgets()
        self.add_widget(Label(text=hour), 0)


        self.data = [day, hour]


class MainView(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['cols'] = 2
        kwargs['size_hint'] = (1.0, 1.0)
        super(MainView, self).__init__(**kwargs)


class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        main = MainView()
        list_widget = ListWidget()
        list_widget.data = ['date', 'time']
        main.add_widget(list_widget)
        Clock.schedule_interval(main.children[0].update, 1)

        return main

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main = MainApp()
    main.run()
```